# How do swap the indexes of a Posts?

Tags: django, django-views

I have `model` with `order` indices, for example  - 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10... (empty indices were allegedly removed - 4, 6, 7, 9...)

I need to get the index and swap it with the nearest index next to it. (for Up and Down move).

What I have:

```
def set_order_index(item: Posts, distinction: int):
    items_to_swap = Posts.objects.filter(
        order_index=item.order_index + distinction)
    if len(items_to_swap) > 0:
        item_to_swap = items_to_swap[0]
        item_to_swap.order_index = item.order_index
        item_to_swap.save()
    item.order_index += distinction
    item.save()
```

And for `Up` views *'+1'*:

```
def up_item(request, id):
    item = Posts.objects.get(id=id)
    set_order_index(item, +1)
    return redirect('index')
```

And for `Down` *'-1'*...

But my `set_order_index` only does +1 and -1 always, and if it gets the same value, then swaps places. That is if index 3, the `set_order_index` will only make 4 (+1), but I need to swap 3 with 5. Because there is no index 4.

And if I use `Post` with index 10 to `Down` - I need to swap with 8, but my `set_order_index` only do -1, and I get only 9. But I need 10 to swap with 8 immediately.

In my head, I understand how to do this through QuerySet, getting the indices of all that is > and < and then select the first or last - it is necessary, the neighbor. But in the code, I can't do it for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def swap_up(item):
    nextItem = Posts.objects.filter(order_index__gt=item.order_index).order_by('order_index').first()
    if nextItem:
        item_index = item.order_index
        item.order_index = nextItem.order_index
        nextItem.order_index = item_index

        item.save()
        nextItem.save()

def swap_down(item):
    prevItem = Posts.objects.filter(order_index__lt=item.order_index).order_by('order_index').last()
    if prevItem:
        item_index = item.order_index
        item.order_index = prevItem.order_index
        prevItem.order_index = item_index

        item.save()
        prevItem.save()
```